# Transforms with $O(N \log N)$ Complexity

Tags: matrices, algorithms, operator-theory, signal-processing

Beside the Discrete Fourier and Walsh-Hadamard operators, are there any non-trivial, bijective  operators that admit an evaluation algorithm of $O(N \log N)$ time complexity or better, whose inverses do the same?

Comment: OK, DCT and DST flavors. Any others?

Comment: The Radon transform I believe has fast discrete versions with complexity of or around $N\log N$.